# Python - Unable to use multiple event loops with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, aio, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a code similar to this one work.

```py
class FooFoo:
    def __init__(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.value = loop.run_until_complete(self.async_work())

    async def async_work(self):
        return 10


def build_server():
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', hello)
    web.run_app(app, 'localhost', '12000')

async def hello(request):
    foo = await FooFoo()
    return web.json_response{'ip': request.remote, 'value': foo.value}
```

Doing a `curl http://127.0.0.1:/` yields this error:

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 418, in start
    resp = await task
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 458, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 155, in handler_wrapper
    result = old_handler(request)
  File "test.py", line 36, in hello
    foo = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(FooFoo())
  File "test.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.value = loop.run_until_complete(self.async_work())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 471, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 425, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

This happens because the server is running on the event loop and `FooFoo` is wants to rerun the loop.

Solutions I've tried :

- Changing the `hello` function into a synchronous one with :
  `foo = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(FooFoo())`, gives the same error.
- Multiprocessing: Running the server instance on another thread/process using libraries : pool, threading, multiprocessing, aioprocessing, this gives a different error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703620/asyncio-event-loop-per-python-process-aioprocessing-multiple-event-loops) gives the same error as multiprocesssing.
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610074/how-to-run-an-aiohttp-server-in-a-thread) as well.

I need to be able to run multiple loops, or if you have a better solution I'd take it.

If it helps I am using python 3.6.8

Comment: Is there any reason why you feel the need to start an event loop in a constructor, blocking it, then trying to await the payload of the event loop again? Are you looking for a factory function perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the logic slightly to something like this:

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp import web


class FooFoo(object):

    async def async_work(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.value = 10


async def hello(request):
    foo = FooFoo()
    await foo.async_work()

    return web.json_response({'ip': request.remote, 'value': foo.value})


def build_server():
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', hello)
    web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

you'll get it working.

**UPDATE** Given the details from the OP comments:

> the FooFoo class is a client that generates a token via asynchronous
>   requests to a server. The user isn't supposed to instantiate FooFoo,
>   then generate a token later.

I'd suggest using a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which is used to simplify creation of complex objects. I think this pattern fits to this case just fine. In order to apply the pattern, we add a new `FooFooBuilder` class:

```
async def request_token():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return 42


class FooFooBuilder(object):
    @staticmethod
    async def build():
        token = await request_token()

        # Do token validation and error handling. 

        return FooFoo(token)
```

The `FooFoo` class will take the `token` as its argument during instantiation:

```
class FooFoo(object):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.value = token
```

So that the `hello` request handler will change to:

```
async def hello(request):
    foo = await FooFooBuilder.build()

    return web.json_response({'ip': request.remote, 'value': foo.value})
```

With this approach, there is no need to use multiple event loops to get things done.

Comment: What I gave was a minimal example, I need some stuff to be done inside the `__init__` function, so I cannot remove it and add another instruction to execute said work. Everything has to be done during instantiation, if I could make the `__init__` `async` then it might fix this specific issue, although it will create many more and anyway it's illegal to use asynchronous magic functions.

Comment: Can you tell me why is this a strict requirement to run async code during instantiation? In the case, you have to wait for some resources to be able to build `FooFoo` instance, then why not to use a factory pattern and collect all the resources asynchronously first, and then, once everything is ready, instantiate the `FooFoo` class?

Comment: the `FooFoo` class is a client that generates a token via asynchronous requests to a server. The user isn't supposed to instantiate `FooFoo`, then generate a token later. The environment needs to stay controlled, so some things are done at instantiation time.

Comment: OK, then why not to create a `FooFooBuilder` class which will request a token and then pass it to `FooFoo` constructor and return its instance? Something like `await foo = FooFooBuilder.build()` where inside this static method a token is requested asynchronously. What I'm trying to say is that you might be complicating things a bit and hitting the wall because of it :)